# Manually set point colors in rCharts + polychart

Tags: r, plot, rcharts, polychart

I try to build a chart using rCharts  and polychart frontend:

```
dtf <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y=c(4, 5, 6, 3, 5), 
              label=c('one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'two'))
color.mapping <- list(one='#ff2385', two='#229922')
p2 <- rPlot(x='x', y='y', data=dtf, type='point', color='label')
print(p2)
```

I would like to have a control over the point colors by either using some sort of discrete mapping  (like in the example above) or using some other logic. How is that done

*EDIT*

following the [Ramnath's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18559821/17523) I tried to do the following, but I get an empty page:

```
dtf <- data.frame(x=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), y=c(4, 5, 6, 3, 5), 
                  label=c('one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'two'))

p2 <- rPlot(x='x', y='y', data=dtf, type='point', color='label')

p2$guides(color = list(scale = "#! function(value){
   color_mapping = {one: '#ff2385', two: '#229922'}
   return color_mapping[value];                  
 } !#"))


print(p2)
```

*Resolution*
upgrading rCharts from github has solved the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little complicated in Polychart currently, although we are trying to create a more R friendly solution. But for now, here is the way to set custom scales in Polychart

```
p2$guides(color = list(scale = "#! function(value){
  color_mapping = {one: '#ff2385', two: '#229922'}
  return color_mapping[value];                  
} !#"))
```

The idea is to set a scale for the color aesthetic. But instead of using a color palette, you specify a function, which returns a color based on the mapping. You need to wrap the function between `#!` and `!#` so that rCharts treats it as a JS literal, and does not stringify it when converting to JSON.

If you are unsure how to specify `color_mapping` in JSON, you can use the function `toJSON` to convert your R object. Only caveat is avoid using double quotes inside the function, as they tend to get escaped and as a result cause errors.

Hope this was useful.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. However, I couldn't adapt your answer to the code (see the addition to the question). Also, there is no toJSON function in my version of rCharts, but there is toJSON2.

Comment: It works for me. Can you make sure that you have the latest dev version of rCharts installed. You can do that by using `devtools::install_github('rCharts', 'ramnathv', ref = 'dev')`

Comment: And the `toJSON` function is from the `RJSONIO` package, and you will have to load it directly, if you are using it outside of `rCharts`.