# How to set different colors for different points in rPlot?

Tags: r, rcharts

I want to set different colors for every point in `rPlot`. I expected it was `rPlot(V2~V1, data=data, type="point", color=color)` where `color` is a vector like `c("#6B7BFDFF", "#A7E7BFFF", "#13A0BBFF", ...)` but this doesn't work. So what is the correct grammar? Thank you.

By the way can I find the documentation of rCharts somewhere? I only see examples on the [project's website](http://ramnathv.github.io/rCharts/).

Answer (score 2):

Documentation is still a work in progress but closer than ever.  If you choose to go with `polycharts` (make sure you are aware of **paid commercial licensing**), then [these examples](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_lattice_book/polycharts_versions/gallery/figure1_01.html) might be helpful.  Here is [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18558473/manually-set-point-colors-in-rcharts-polychart) on the same topic.  I made a quick example below.

```
    library(rCharts)


    data(iris)
    colnames(iris) <- sapply(colnames(iris), FUN = gsub, pattern = "\\.", replacement = "")
    p5 <- rPlot(SepalWidth ~ SepalLength, data = iris, color = "Species", type = "point", height = 400)
    # again match polychartjs example exactly to show how we can change axis and legend titles
    p5$guides(color = list(scale = "#! function(value){
      color_mapping = {versicolor: '#ff2385',setosa:'#229922',virginica:'#2B24D6'}
      return color_mapping[value];                  
    } !#"), y = list(title = "sepalWidth"), x = list(title = "sepalLength"))
    p5$set(title = "Iris Flowers")
    p5
```

If you choose to use another library, specifying the color will be different, so let me know and I'll be glad to help out.

Comment: Thank you. I read that question and the answer before. But in that question it's about remapping some default colors coming from the grouping (like `Species`). But I want to give different colors for different points (so I have roughly 1000 elements in the color vector). I think my case is different and that's why I asked. When I mention the documentation, I mean, for example, I don't know how to use the `p$guides` or `p$set` as you do.

Comment: do you want to specify a unique color for each point?  are you trying to do a gradient?

Comment: main issue with documentation is I can't find how to do in `polycharts`.  If you know how to do in `polycharts`, then it is fairly easy to translate.

Comment: I am not bound to `polycharts` so if it can be done with other libraries like `nvd3` I'll be fine with it.

Comment: I am doing dimensional reduction to a 2-sphere (from 3D to 2D) so I want to use color to indicate the original coordinates, the idea is similar to the figure 2 of [this paper](http://jmlr.org/papers/volume11/venna10a/venna10a.pdf).